Как добавить значение к уже существующему значению в словаре Python
pets = [('Hatiko', 'Parker', 'Wilson', 50),
        ('Rusty', 'Josh', 'King', 25),
        ('Fido', 'John', 'Smith', 28),
        ('Butch', 'Jake', 'Smirnoff', 18),
        ('Odi', 'Emma', 'Wright', 18),
        ('Balto', 'Josh', 'King', 25),
        ('Barry', 'Josh', 'King', 25),
        ('Snape', 'Hannah', 'Taylor', 40),
        ('Horry', 'Martha', 'Robinson', 73),
        ('Giro', 'Alex', 'Martinez', 65),
        ('Zooma', 'Simon', 'Nevel', 32),
        ('Lassie', 'Josh', 'King', 25),
        ('Chase', 'Martha', 'Robinson', 73),
        ('Ace', 'Martha', 'Williams', 38),
        ('Rocky', 'Simon', 'Nevel', 32)]


result = {}

for tup in pets:
    if tup not in result:
        result[tup[1], tup[2], tup[3]] = [tup[0]]
    else:
        result[tup[1], tup[2], tup[3]].append(tup[0])

print(result)

задача в том, чтобы он взял имя фамилию и возраст хозяина и сделал их ключом словаря, это работает,
tup[0], т.е кличку собаки он делает значением словаря,
однако строка
else:
        result[tup[1], tup[2], tup[3]].append(tup[0])

не добавляет ещё одно значение к ключу словаря, почему?
В примере у Josh King 25 есть несколько собак, но он сохраняет только последнюю - Lassie, как это исправить и добавить всех собак?
Попытался сделать через append, так как значение - список, и в него через append можно добавить новые значения, но он их не добавляет

Потому что условие if tup not in result: всегда истинно

а почему так, ведь если изначально tup не было, я его создаю путём
 result[tup[1], tup[2], tup[3]] = [tup[0]]

а затем добавляю аппендом к значению текущий tup который пробегает цикл

Перечитайте что вы написали - вы создаёте tup[1], tup[2], tup[3], но никакой tup вы не создаёте

действительно, переписав на
if (tup[1], tup[2], tup[3]) not in result:
все сработало, просто даже не думал что так можно задать условие, спасибо вам большое!

мб всё упаковать в словарь и использовать дизьюнкцию?

@ganz я вас даже не понял...

@facecaat я не верно выразился, но в целом я об этом https://docs.python.org/3.9/whatsnew/3.9.html те о первой особенности

Вот так может вам будет гораздо понятнее и проще не запутаться. Этот код работает:
for val, *key in pets:
    key = tuple(key)
    if key not in result:
        result[key] = [val]
    else:
        result[key].append(val)


действительно, так понятнее, сначала не понял *key, а потом вспомнил, что он берет все оставшиеся значения, благодарю за приятный и читаемый код, возьму на заметку!

@facecaat Я ещё чуть уменьшил код, убрал лишнюю переменную. А так то я прямо не люблю индексирование, да ещё и если его повторять несколько раз - очень легко в нём запутаться. Упаковка/распаковка переменных гораздо удобнее выглядит на мой взгляд.

from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)

for pet, *owner in pets:
    result[tuple(owner)].append(pet)

Не нужно проверять наличие ключа в словаре. При присваивании словарь сам это делает автоматически.
defaultdict автоматически создает новый ключ и пустой список для него, если ключа еще нет, при этом в список сразу можно добавлять значения.
